# Android ItemTouchHelper.Callback Shorten Long Press Duration

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, long-press

I want to know if there is a way to shorten the long press during.

To be more specific, I am working on a Drag-and-Drop thing in recyclerview.

```
@Override
public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

By overriding the above method in ItemTouchHelper.Callback, I could drag my view. But I feel the threshold for a long press is too long.

Is  there a way to shorten the time?

Comment: I don't think you can change the long press duration. It's a fixed gesture. You might want to take a look at methods like `onTouchEvent`.

Comment: Thank you @VamsiAbbineni    I agree with your point, if i want to customize the duration, I'm afraid that I have to build a new class similar to ItemTouchHelper from the ground.

Comment: Yes you can change this to straight. I would recommend you to add a dragArea on the left side of an element to match the guidelines. As example check out my video how I've done it:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_gcw_lobGA

Comment: did you solve this problem ?